# pitched yeast at too high of temp,is all lost?

Tags: yeast

I am new to home brewing and I believe I messed first batch up.It was a american amber kit and I did well on instructions until I pitched the yeast.It was supposed to be at 65 to 72 when I pitched yeast but I realized it was 86 instead. I put all in primary fermenter that night,and in morning it had blown airlock out.I then put it back in,and it blew it off again.It was really vigirous and foaming good.This was at about 12 hours. I  then transferred it to my pla

Comment: What's pla? Please remember that this is an international site and not everyone will be familiar with all the shortcuts etc.

Comment: How long did it take to drop to your desired temp of 65 to 72? Also what style of beer and strain of yeast?

Comment: I think the poster inadvertently chopped off the end of their post. I suppose "pla" was something like "plastic fermentation vessel" or similar. Indeed the end of the question may be missing as there is no question actually posed.

Comment: Actual question is in the title. If chopped part will turn out to change much, I'll update or delete my answer.

Answer (score 3):

You have vigorous fermentation. That's the surest sign your yeast are feeling just fine! If it was too vigorous, it might mean you fermented too warm and it will probably affect taste, but that's OK for now, you will know when you taste it.

Do nothing. Let it ferment. Try to make sure you are at the middle, or lower half, of the yeast temperatures. And wait. It is still quite possible you will have a very drinkable brew. And if it is ruined, you can't know it now anyway.